# Sequence numbering in XSLT 1.0

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-grouping

Hi need some help in **XSLT** formatting for creating a sequence number for **Element tag**. Mostly **Element tag** misses some numbers in sequence and i need to get an output in a sequential format as shown below by adding missing numbers to **Element tag** in the same sequence of **Seat tag**.

Any help in this is much appreciated, thanks in advance.

**Input**

```
<book>
<Seat>
    <seatNumber>12A</seatNumber>
    <Element>1</Element>
    <Number>1</Number>
</Seat>
<Seat>
    <seatNumber>12B</seatNumber>
    <Element>3</Element>
    <Number>1</Number>
</Seat>
<Seat>
    <seatNumber>12C</seatNumber>
    <Element>4</Element>
    <Number>1</Number>
</Seat>
<Seat>
    <seatNumber>12D</seatNumber>
    <Element>5</Element>
    <Number>1</Number>
</Seat>
<Seat>
    <seatNumber>12E</seatNumber>
    <Element>7</Element>
    <Number>1</Number>
</Seat>
</book>
```

**Output**

```
<book>
<Seat>
    <seatNumber>12A</seatNumber>
    <Element>1</Element>
    <Number>1</Number>
</Seat>
<Seat>
    <seatNumber>12B</seatNumber>
    <Element>2</Element>
    <Number>1</Number>
</Seat>
<Seat>
    <seatNumber>12C</seatNumber>
    <Element>3</Element>
    <Number>1</Number>
</Seat>
<Seat>
    <seatNumber>12D</seatNumber>
    <Element>4</Element>
    <Number>1</Number>
</Seat>
<Seat>
    <seatNumber>12E</seatNumber>
    <Element>5</Element>
    <Number>1</Number>
</Seat>
</book>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it this way:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Element">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:number count="Seat"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanx this works..is there any other way with out making use of templates?

Comment: What exactly is your objection to using templates?

Comment: I need to use it in xslt which have other manipulation’s as well and need to implement in BPEL

Comment: If you have other manipulations, then add more templates to handle them. Or add `xsl:number` to your existing stylesheet (which you haven't showed us). I am afraid I know nothing about BPEL. The above is the most convenient way to accomplish the given task in XSLT.